# how to get users with usermeta include array of an array

Tags: user-meta, array

i have a user_meta for users that them is array like below:

```
user_saved_posts = [31289,31482,27641]
```

and i want to get users that their user_meta include an item of an array like below:

```
goal_posts = [31289,31422,77641,41289,21482,17641]
```

if user have an item of goal_posts array must returned them.
i use below code but this code worked if i have a value for search in user_meta

```
$args = [
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                [
                    'key' => 'saved_posts',
                    'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', 31289),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    get_users($args);
```

Comment: For this kind of purpose, you shouldn't save your meta as a single array. As default, WordPress saves the meta in multiple fields, unless you explicitly say not to. When you're adding user meta, set the `unique` parameter to false, and then your code will work. Note that in this way you have 3 `user_saved_posts` meta instead of a single array. Let me know if you needed any more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in another way(**WPDB**).
I wrote a query for this purpose like below:

```
$goal_posts = [31289,31422,77641,41289,21482,17641];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE (meta_key = 'saved_posts') AND (";
$sql .= implode(" OR ", $goal_posts);
$sql .= ') GROUP BY user_id';
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```